# NSJSONSerialization Not Creating Key Value Pairs

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I am using iOS 5 new feature to parse JSON and I have no idea that why I am not getting any key value pairs. "aStr" (string representation of data) is putting the right JSON on the output window but I am getting nothing in "dicData" and there is no error either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I am using

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL        URLWithString:@"http://www.macscandal.com/?json=get_post&post_id=436"]];

NSString* aStr;
aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"data = %@",aStr);
NSDictionary *dicData = [NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                           options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                           error:&error];
//NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
NSString *title = [dicData objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is formatted this way:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "post": {
    "id": 436,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "foxconn-likely-to-get-assembly-contract-for-apple-tv-set",
    "url": "http:\/\/www.macscandal.com\/index.php\/2011\/12\/28\/foxconn-likely-to-get-assembly-contract-for-apple-tv-set\/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "Foxconn Likely to get Assembly Contract for Apple TV Set",
...
```

I haven't used `NSJSONSerialization` but just following the natural JSON parsing alg this is how I would try to get it.

```
NSDictionary *dicData = [NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                           options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                           error:&error];

NSDictionary *postData = [dicData objectForKey:@"post"];
NSString *title = [postData objectForKey:@"title"];
```

**EDIT**

Just a simple check method:

```
-(void)check{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.macscandal.com/?json=get_post&post_id=436"]];

    NSDictionary *dicData = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:data
                             options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                             error:&error];

    NSDictionary *postData = [dicData objectForKey:@"post"];
    NSString *title = [postData objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSLog(@"%@", title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cyprian but I am still getting 0 key/value pairs? Any idea?

Comment: Not sure why that's the case. I will try to check it.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me: `2011-12-31 20:42:04.595 UIView Demo[2406:f803] Foxconn Likely to get Assembly Contract for Apple TV Set`

Comment: How are you checking it's value?

Comment: Really!!! I am doing exactly as you mentioned in your answer. Can you post your piece of code? Thanks

Comment: I just did post a check method that I used

Comment: School boy mistake. iPhone 4.3 was selected in simulator. Never noticed that. Thanks a ton for helping me out here.